# Need plan of action to upgrade graphics toolkit in company's applications

Tags: methods, upgrade, visual-studio-2003, openscenegraph

My job is to upgrade all of our applications that use OpenSceneGraph (an openGl toolkit) version 0.9.9 to the latest and greatest 2.8. Well quite a few caveats come with this task:

1.) After version .9.9 there was a major overhaul the the core OpenSceneGraph (OSG). Commonly used functions and classes were added and removed. Simply put, I can't just replace the old with the new and modify a few deprecated or removed functions - there is a lot that needs to be changed.

2.) Our applications were built using MFC in Visual Studio 2003. They want me to stick with using that for the upgrade.

3.) Good organized documentation for my particular scenerio for OSG seems impossible to find and unorganized and scattered at best.

My question is: What would be a somewhat detailed methodical approach for tackling this problem. I've got about two weeks to upgrade one of the applications. The plan is then to follow and apply this approach for the rest of the applications. For me, the biggest hurdle is finding a starting point. On most projects I work on, I can easily just dig right in and figure it out with a little organization and plan at hand. This seems like a bit more convoluted problem, with a more accurate and precise plan of action needed. Your ideas and suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should upgrade your osg to new version and try to build it again until you get no exception.

for every exception which is not solved easily, you can ask to osg-mailing list.

you can also ask what are the major changes with your current version and latest version.